# Div with background won't show

Tags: html

Okay so this is what I'm printing:

```
<a href=\"portfoliodetail.php?id=$id\" class=\"noHover\" title=\"$title\">
     <div class=\"thumbnailHome\" style=\"background: url('images/portfolio/thumbnails/$bgthumbnail'); background-position: center center;\">f</div>
</a>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.thumbnailHome {
    max-width: 28%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.thumbnailHome a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0%;
}
```

However, the divs printed won't show. When I inspect the element it says the height and width are both 0. When I put a bit of text in it, the div and the background display but only as big as the text.

I gave it a max-width of 28 so I could have three divs next to each other (and they would scale if the screen gets smaller). I would like to keep this future but I've got no clue on how to fix this so that the divs would show up? I don't understand why the width and height are 0?

link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R4mGY/

Comment: try using abosulte sizes like "500px"

Comment: "Okay so this is what I'm printing:" how are you printing this?

Comment: Well I could but I want the div to scale when the browser window is being resized. And I'm just printing this in a for loop through PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help out.

your css isn't placed right.

Take a look at the jsFiddle.

```
a:last-child div {
    margin-right: 0%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fuzm/

**Updated Code**
The below code works when there is no text.

http://jsfiddle.net/4fuzm/2/

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it still doesn't work. When removing the text the div again won't show up. And since my divs are empty, nothing shows up. Btw could you maybe explain why my CSS what wrong and I should use this instead? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: If you look at your html code `<a href=\"portfoliodetail.php?id=$id\" class=\"noHover\" title=\"$title\">
     <div class=\"thumbnailHome\" style=\"background: url('images/portfolio/thumbnails/$bgthumbnail'); background-position: center center;\">f</div>
</a>` your anchor tag is a parent to the div that has the class "thumbnailHome" and your css is `.thumbnailHome a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0%;
}` so you won't be able to do anything to the anchor tag there.