# Placing div on top of image?

Tags: css, html

I was wondering whether it was possible to place a div on top of an image. I looked it up and apparently it should work and I tried some methods with extra containers and z-index but nothing really seems to be working when I do that. I have this now but my text div that should be on top of the image is just floating around at some weird places.

```
<a href="portfoliodetail.php?id=<?=$id?>" title="<?=$title?>">
    <div class="latestWorkTitle"><?=$title?></div>
    <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/<?=$bgthumbnail?>" alt="<?=$title?>" class="noMargin" />
</a>

<style>
    latestWork a img {
        max-width: 28%;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 7%;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .latestWorkTitle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` needs to have `position: relative`, and then it's children have `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly the solution you're looking for, but why not try to place the image as the `background-image` of the div like so:

```
.selector {
  background-image: url('../img/img.png');
}
```

If you're trying to do this dynamically with PHP, you can save CSS files as .php files, and including variable names. This seems like a superiorly easier option.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. I tried that already but unfortunately I come up with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155909/div-with-background-wont-show problem then.